# Solve a polynomial equation in Java

Tags: java, collections, polynomial-math

I have an equation.

a<sup>4</sup> + b<sup>4</sup> = c<sup>4</sup> + d<sup>4</sup>

The variables a, b, c and d can take any value from 0 to 1000. Write a program that would print all possible pairs of a, b and c, d that satisfy the above equation.

I tried to do it using Java.

One of the approaches I attempted was to build a map containing the key value pairs : <0,0<sup>4</sup>>, <1,1<sup>4</sup>>, <2,2<sup>4</sup>>....<1000,1000<sup>4</sup>>. After the map is built, I am looking to iterate through the values list and see if the sum of two elements in the list match the sum of two other elements in the list. I am stuck at this point.

```
public static void getMatchingPairs()
    {
        long a;
        long b;
        long c;
        long d;
        Map<Integer,Long> map = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1001; i++)
        {
            long res = Double.valueOf(Math.pow(i, 4)).longValue();
            map.put(i,res);
        }

        List<Long> lst = (List<Long>) map.values();
    }
```

Comment: Are pairs ordered? E.g. is `(1,2),(1,2)` different from `(1,2),(2,1)`, `(2,1),(1,2)`, and `(2,1),(2,1)`? Is that 1 or 4 "possible pairs"?

Comment: It seems to me this is not an equation. For example 10 = 10 => 7+3 = 2+8 | then you just get the log based 4 or each number.

Comment: @Andreas Those are 4 valid pairs.

Comment: @Juan The values are integers between 0 and 1000. Sure, the "integer" part is not stated, but it makes no sense otherwise, since there would be unlimited solutions otherwise.

Comment: Ok got it: The log base 4 or the number has to be an integer between 0 and 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `double` math to calculate power of 4. Just multiply 3 times, i.e. calculate `a*a*a*a + b*b*b*b`.

Then create a `Map` of the result to a `List` of the pairs used to calculate the result: `Map<Long, List<int[]>>` where the `int[]` is an array of two values, i.e. a "pair".

As an example, the pair `(1,2)` results in value `17`, so does reverse pair `(2,1)`. Since those are the only pairs with that result, your maps would include `17 = [(1,2), (2,1)]`.

Not sure what *"print all possible pairs of a, b and c, d"* means. Simple answer is just those 2 pairs (for result `17`).

More complex answer is that you need to print each combination of pairs, since each pair can be an `(a,b)` pair or a `(c,d)` pair, so you create all combination of pairs: `(1,2),(1,2)`, `(1,2),(2,1)`, `(2,1),(1,2)`, and `(2,1),(2,1)`.

That all seems very redundant, because for each `(a,b)` pair where `a != b`, there will be 4 combinations, so perhaps you only need to print results of a pair (not combination of pairs), and only when `a <= b`, since `a > b` is redundant.

Anyway, you need to print from all the value lists in the map for the full answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Andres' comments, using an LongStream is a much more natural solution.

Lets assume that a^4 + b^4 = b^4 + a^4 is not an interesting solution so instead what you want to find is when a <= b and c and d != a or b

```
    Map<Long, List<long[]>> sums = LongStream.range(0, 1001)
            .boxed()
            .flatMap(a -> LongStream.range(a, 1001)
                    .boxed()
                    .map(b -> new long[]{a, b, a * a * a * a + b * b * b * b}))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(triple -> triple[2]));
    sums.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(
                    e.getValue().stream()
                            .map(t -> "(" + t[0] + "," + t[1] + ")")
                            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))));
```

I have included the code here for you interest as you wouldn't be expect to write this for your homework yet.

Comment: The title says Java, but if someone is interested, I have what I think is a simpler solution in Python.